# Be careful with this message The sender hasn't authenticated this message so Gmail can't verify that it actually came from them

Tags: dns

Looking for some solution here:
When a customer places an order on our website they get order confirmation email.
**How do we generate email:**
Website is build in PHP
We use elasticemail api to generate and send the email

**What actions we have taken so far:**
Updated our DNS record with: SPIF, DKIM, CNAME and DMARC records.
Verified details with Google Console and have added their SPIF and DKIM record.

Even after doing this, the emails which are going out are showing below as header:
*"Be careful with this message
The sender hasn't authenticated this message so Gmail can't verify that it actually came from them."*

When checked email message header SPF shows:
SPF:    SOFTFAIL with IP 182.50.xxx.xxx

Has anybody faced similar issue or knows how to address this?

**What we tried:**

Updated our DNS record with: SPIF, DKIM, CNAME and DMARC records.
Verified details with Google Console and have added their SPIF and DKIM record.

**What we were expecting:**
customers won't be presented with below message and our branding for the email portfolio will appear considering we have validated our domain on google and elasticcapi
*"Be careful with this message
The sender hasn't authenticated this message so Gmail can't verify that it actually came from them."*